# personal allowances

Tags: meaning

Source: [Alliances crumble along the Crimean border](http://www.aljazeera.com/indepth/features/2015/12/alliances-crumble-crimean-border-151219110155013.html)

Example:

> The people on the blockades search cars travelling to Crimea and confiscate anything they think is going to be sold there. Drivers are given **personal allowances** of building supplies, food, and other goods, as long as the Ukrainian items are not destined for retail.

What exactly are personal allowances of something and why do they give them to drivers?

Comment: As long as drivers can justify the personal need for such items, and that they would not be sold, they won't be confiscated.

Comment: User is essentially correct. But deciding if items are for "personal use" is more about perception of the people running the blockade than it is about the reality of the driver. Think about it like this. One bag of sugar would OK. 50 would be too many. Somewhere between the two there is a fuzzy breaking point where the guy running the road block wouldn't believe the driver that the bags of sugar were for personal use.

Comment: [Further reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_allowance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **personal allowance** is usually considered to be an amount which would be consumed or used by a **normal person** under **normal circumstances**. It is usually associated when there is a **conditional restriction** on something **above which amount a tax is levied**.

For example, when boarding an airplane, a case where overhead storage space is constrained, passengers are allowed a laptop and **one personal carry-on**.  The personal carry-on is a **personal allowance**, above this amount, the passenger would have to check-in they bag and **potentially pay a fee**.

Another example is a **minimum income amount** below which there are **no taxes withheld or paid**. This is a **personal income allowance**.

Another example is when goods which are being transported, could both be **used** by the passenger or potentially **resold** in an **aftermarket**.  This consideration frequently this comes up in cases involving cigarettes being transported **across taxation boundaries**, where there is a set amount allowed by customs per traveller. There can also be a **burden of proof** that the item(s) being carried will **not be resold**.  In a fairly (in)famous case, a passenger brought in a suitcase full of cigarettes, obviously **above the personal allowance**. When questioned by authorities about this, the claim was **personal use**. To prove this, every packet of cigarettes was opened with one cigarette missing.  Obviously, the cigarettes could not have been freely resold.